# Problem with displaying photos in chat - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I'm writing a phone application for college and I have a huge problem that when I want to send a photo via chat, a link to it appears in the chat instead of the photo. The photo is in the database. I've tried everything, even AI help, but unfortunately nothing helped me. In the debugger I see all the time that it reads the photo as text, that's why it pastes it that way. Below is the code.

```
package com.example.navibuzz;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import java.util.List;

public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Message> messages;

    private static final int TYPE_TEXT = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        Log.d("MessageAdapter", "Position: " + position + ", Type: " + message.getMessageType());
        if (message.getMessageType().equals("text")) {
            return TYPE_TEXT; // Stała reprezentująca typ tekstowy
        } else if (message.getMessageType().equals("image")) {
            return TYPE_IMAGE; // Stała reprezentująca typ obrazu
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_TEXT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_item_text, parent, false);
            return new TextMessageViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_item_image, parent, false);
            return new ImageMessageViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case TYPE_TEXT:
                TextMessageViewHolder textHolder = (TextMessageViewHolder) holder;
                textHolder.messageTextView.setText(message.getContent());
                break;
            case TYPE_IMAGE:
                ImageMessageViewHolder imageHolder = (ImageMessageViewHolder) holder;
                Log.d("MessageAdapter", "Loading Image: " + message.getContent());
                Glide.with(imageHolder.itemView.getContext())
                        .load(message.getContent())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                Log.e("Glide", "Error loading image", e);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                Log.d("Glide", "Image loaded successfully");
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .into(imageHolder.messageImageView);
                break;
        }
    }






    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    static class TextMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageTextView;

        TextMessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            messageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        }
    }

    static class ImageMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView messageImageView;

        ImageMessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            messageImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to offer an answer without more information like the kind of data that is populated in your `Message` class. It very well could be that your logic is wrong and instead of using the image viewholder, it's using the text viewholder. It's just a matter of debugging your code and see if it's doing that. Just place the necessary break points and that should tell you.